# swapping rails3 layout on the fly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have am trying to dig into twitter bootstrap and rails3 sites that actually look and function well (new to it all).  I have this feature I want where I have a twitter bootstrap navigation (specified in what I guess is the default application layout) that calls a _navigation.erb.html etc.  This works great, but on that navigation i want a "Se Habla Espanol" or what not, where when the user clicks there, the navigation text all changes to spanish.  i thought easiest would be have another _navigationespanol.erb.html or something that changes the navigation words all around and also when click (toggling into spanish mode) it sets all the text in the pages to spanish by anytime there is a text render or whatever a variable flag was set and is interrogated on page index render show or what have you and it renders spanish or english words...

So ideally click on see it all in spanish, it loads a new layout (my main question) that has the spanish navigation and messages and other twitter bootstrap stuff and it also sets a global var i can look at in other renders to see if im rendering english or spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than swapping layouts, it seems that you need to implement `Internationalization (I18n)`.  In such case you'll have to create an directory `config/locales` that holds a .yaml file for each of the language you're trying to have translation for, for instance:

```
# on a file called en.yml
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
```

For a complete guide on how to go about it: [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Hmm is it all only based on incoming URL?  This is for a site thats all usa based, but gives spanish speaking users the option to switch to that (why i thought a simple layout swap and global var to know what to render (spanish or english) on other information pages) was the way to go.

Comment: Not quite, you can have it behave as such, but can can also provide a link for them to do the switch between different language. For instance: `<%= link_to "spanish", :controller => 'locale', :action => 'set', :id => 'es' %>` and the will change the complete site to use the spanish (es) locale. This is the way to go, since you only need to maintain one layout and different `.yaml` for every language.

Comment: The scenario you describe in the post is the whole idea why the `Rails Internationalization (I18n) API` was born. The same goes for other languages as well.

Comment: okay then since I know that is the direction to go i will read up on the I18n thanks!